# How to export data files stored in GG Bigquery into GZ folder?

Tags: google-bigquery, gzip

I am using a similar code to the one below to extract zip files from bquery to GCS.
Sometimes it is about 90 files that I need to extract. I would like to extract one zipped folder instead of sending files one by one.
**Note:** I am using Jupyter.
Thanks for your help.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()

project_id = 'fh-bigquery'
dataset_id = 'public_dump'
table_id = 'afinn_en_165'


bucket_name = 'your_bucket'

destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, 'file.csv.gz')

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
job_config.compression = 'GZIP'
extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref,
    destination_uri,
    job_config = job_config
) 
extract_job.result()`
```

Comment: Do you mean that you are trying to extract from 90 different tables at once?

Comment: Hey, no. I mean that using the bucketing I am extracting 90 files that are compressed, while I prefer to compress all the files together before extracting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is not a possible way to extract the whole dataset using a single API request. To export the corresponding tables into the Google Cloud Storage bucket, I would employ the following code that iterates through the tableIDs storing each one at a time:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.oauth2 import service_account

key_path = "SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH"
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(\
    key_path,
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud- platform"],)

client = bigquery.Client()

project_id = 'PROJECT_ID'
dataset_id = 'DATASET_ID'
bucket_name = 'BUCKET_NAME'

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project_id)

for t in client.list_tables(dataset_ref):

    print("Extracting table {}".format(t.table_id))

    zip_file = '{}.csv.zip'.format(t.table_id)
    destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, zip_file)

    table_ref = dataset_ref.table(t.table_id)

    job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig()
    job_config.compression = 'GZIP'
    extract_job = client.extract_table(
        table_ref,
        destination_uri,
        job_config = job_config
    )
    extract_job.result()
```